# I can't run cqlengine on centos

Tags: django, centos, cql

I installed python 2.7 and django 1.5 on centos server. I installed cqlengine too but when I want to run my project
This error happen:
can not import model cqlengine
CAn any one help me what shoud I do..
Thanks

Comment: could you post the traceback?

Comment: These are the erroes:

Comment: python2.6 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
Validating models...

Unhandled exception in thread started by <bound method Command.inner_run of <django.contrib.staticfiles.management.commands.runserver.Command object at 0x28d83d0>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Django-1.5.1-py2.6.egg/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 92, in inner_run
    self.validate(display_num_errors=True)

Comment: File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Django-1.5.1-py2.6.egg/django/core/management/base.py", line 280, in validate
    num_errors = get_validation_errors(s, app)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Django-1.5.1-py2.6.egg/django/core/management/validation.py", line 35, in get_validation_errors
    for (app_name, error) in get_app_errors().items():
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Django-1.5.1-py2.6.egg/django/db/models/loading.py", line 166, in get_app_errors
    self._populate()

Comment: File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Django-1.5.1-py2.6.egg/django/db/models/loading.py", line 72, in _populate
    self.load_app(app_name, True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Django-1.5.1-py2.6.egg/django/db/models/loading.py", line 96, in load_app
    models = import_module('.models', app_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Django-1.5.1-py2.6.egg/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module

Comment: File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Django-1.5.1-py2.6.egg/django/db/models/loading.py", line 96, in load_app
    models = import_module('.models', app_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Django-1.5.1-py2.6.egg/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/srv/www/Viral360/MainApp/models.py", line 1, in <module>
    from cqlengine import columns
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/cqlengine-0.5.2-py2.6.egg/cqlengine/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from cqlengine.columns import *

Comment: File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/cqlengine-0.5.2-py2.6.egg/cqlengine/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from cqlengine.columns import *
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/cqlengine-0.5.2-py2.6.egg/cqlengine/columns.py", line 501
    return {self.value_col.validate(envy) for v in val}

Answer (score 0):

You need to upgrade python on your centos box. It looks like you're using python 2.6 on your centos box. Set comprehensions (what's happening in the cqlengine file) were not introduced until python 2.7. That's most likely your problem.